# How to prove any $N \times N$ matrix $M$, satisfying $M^2 = \lambda^2 I_{N\times N}$, $\lambda\neq 0$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove following things.

Any $N \times N$ matrix $M$, satisfying $M^2 = \lambda^2 I_{N\times N}$, with $\lambda\neq 0$ is diagonalizable.

Can you give me some hint or proof of this?

My trail starts from determinant
\begin{align}
0=det(M^2 - \lambda^2 I) = det(M - \lambda I) det(M+ \lambda I)
\end{align}
thus i conclude that either $det(M - \lambda I)=0$ or $ det(M+ \lambda I)=0$. 
But i don't know how to go further..

Comment: The minimal polynomial for $M$ can only be $x-\lambda$, $x+\lambda$ or $x^2-\lambda^2$; in all cases, the minimal polynomial has distinct roots.

Comment: What is $\lambda$, an eigenvalue of M? If so, which eigenvalue?

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez, $\lambda$ is just a number. But It turns out $\pm \lambda $ is an eigenvalues for $M$. (That proof is what i want to know)

Comment: @egreg, how the minimal polynomial and diagonalizable related to each other exactly. First i know that diagonalizable matrix has distinct roots, So i can guess if the minimal polynomial has distinct roots, the matrix is diagonalizable. Then for minimal polynomial for $M^2$ which is $x^2 - \lambda^2$ i can assure that it has distinct roots so it is diagonalizable. But how about $M$?

Comment: @phy_math A diagonalizable $n\times n$ matrix need not have $n$ distinct eigenvalues: don't make the error of considering necessary a condition that's only sufficient for diagonalizability. The theorem that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has distinct roots follows from Jordan normal form.

Answer (score -1):

As $M^2$ is in diagonal form, then we can write it's diagonalization $M^2=I(\lambda^2 I)I=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$. Then we can write $M^2 = I(\lambda I)(\lambda I)I=Q\sqrt{\Lambda}\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^{-1}$. Then we can also write $M^2=Q\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^{-1}Q\sqrt{\Lambda}Q^{-1} = I(\lambda I)II(\lambda I)I=MM$. So from this derivation we see that $M=\lambda I$ with possible eigenvalues $\pm \lambda$.